# Passing a value through a button in PHP

Tags: php, button

I want to pass `$record['userId']` value through **delete** button into an another php function. How can I do this? I want to delete the column respond to the current userId.

```
if($result_set){
  $table = '<table class="table">';
  $table .='<tr><th>Record No.</th><th>Race ID</th><th>User ID</th><th>Message</th><th>Date &</th><th></th><th></th></tr>';
  $count = 1;
  while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $count . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $record['userId'] . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $record['raceId'] . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $record['message'] . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $record['createdAt'] . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Record Actions" style="float:left" >
        <a href="inc/edit.php" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>                                        
      </div>
    </td>';  

    $table .= '<td>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Record Actions" style="float:left" >                                        
        <a href="inc/delete.php" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </td>';  
    $table .= '</tr>';
    $count = $count+1;
  }

  $table .='</table>';
  echo $table;
} else {
  echo "Query Failed"; 
}
```

Comment: Hidden input in a form or as a query string.

Comment: It gives me this error "syntax error, unexpected 'userId' (T_STRING)"

Comment: What is giving you that error and on what line?

Comment: Are you sure to use only PHP to delete it ? Or can go with AJAX / JQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use this button;

```
<a href="inc/delete.php?userId="'.$record['userId'].'" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

And now at `inc/delete.php` use `$_GET['userId']` to receive the userId

So, total will be;

```
 if($result_set){

                        $table = '<table class="table">';
                        $table .='<tr><th>Record No.</th><th>Race ID</th><th>User ID</th><th>Message</th><th>Date &</th><th></th><th></th></tr>';
                        $count = 1;
                        while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)){
                            $table .= '<tr>';
                            $table .= '<td>' . $count . '</td>';
                            $table .= '<td>' . $record['userId'] . '</td>';
                            $table .= '<td>' . $record['raceId'] . '</td>';
                            $table .= '<td>' . $record['message'] . '</td>';
                            $table .= '<td>' . $record['createdAt'] . '</td>';
                            $table .= 
                            '<td>
                                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Record Actions" style="float:left" >
                                    <a href="inc/edit.php" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>                                        
                                </div>
                            </td>';  

                            $table .= 
                            '<td>
                                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Record Actions" style="float:left" >                                        
                                    <a href="inc/delete.php?userId="'.$record['userId'].'" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                </div>
                            </td>';  
                            $table .= '</tr>';
                            $count = $count+1;
                        }

                        $table .='</table>';

                        echo $table;
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "Query Failed"; 
                    }
```

Comment: It gives a null value. "http://localhost/typr/inc/delete.php?userId=" is shown in addressbar.

Comment: **Warning!** This is wide open to [CSRF attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)). If someone creates a direct link to `delete.php` with some other ID and then gets the admin to click on it, it will delete that user. You should add CSRF-tokens when doing stuff like this.

Comment: @shayanmalinda Then `$record['userId']` is not set?

Comment: @AaronJonk it is set

Comment: @shayanmalinda thats impossible, does it show up in the table?

Comment: @AaronJonk yes. It is

Comment: @AaronJonk It worked. Your answer was missing " at the end. Thank You.